# How to know which Linq statement produced the SQL on hand during runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to write Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL queries in a way so that when I see a SQL query in SQL Server Profiler, I can quickly identify which LINQ statement produced that SQL, without going into the debugger and tracing it down. The app won't use stored procedures which make it easy to search by proc name.

Any ideas? Is there a way to inject static string with codes in a LINQ query only for the purpose of identifying the query without having an effect in query results?

**Update**
I am adding this in response to logging suggestions. I don't want to have logging running in production all the time just in the event I need look at some SQL when there's an issue. Looking for a way that has mininal cost to performance. Appending some unique string to every linq statement so that the code can be correlated to the SQL very easily?

Comment: With Linq2SQl, you can just set the `Log` property to any TextWriter, not sure about EF.

Comment: @leppie I don't want to be logging. This can be in production

Comment: Why not filter per process then (assuming everything is coming from 'linq')?

Comment: Everything is coming from IIS. It's an ASP.NETapp. I don't understand how filtering by process tells you which SQL goes with which LINQ statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an extension method you can use to tag your Entity Framework queries:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static IQueryable<T> SetQueryName<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    [CallerMemberName] String name = null,
    [CallerFilePath] String sourceFilePath = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] Int32 sourceLineNumber = 0)
  {
    var expr = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Constant("Query name: " + name), Expression.Constant(null));
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "param");
    var criteria1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(expr, param);

    expr = Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Constant($"Source: {sourceFilePath} ({sourceLineNumber})"), Expression.Constant(null));
    var criteria2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(expr, param);

    return source.Where(criteria1).Where(criteria2);
  }
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
context.Table1.SetQueryName().Where(x => x.C1 > 4)
```

It will use the calling method name as the query name.

You can specify another name like this:

```
context.Table1.SetQueryName("Search for numbers > 4").Where(x => x.Number > 4)
```

Here is how the SQL will look like:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number]
    FROM (SELECT 
    [Table1].[Number] AS [Number]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Table1]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE
      (N'Query name: Search for numbers > 4' IS NOT NULL)
      AND
      (N'Source: C:\Code\Projects\MyApp\Program.cs (49)' IS NOT NULL)
      AND ([Extent1].[Number] > 4)
```

Comment: Awesome! Your're a LINQ wizard. Everything I need shows up in SQL Profiler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ToTraceString` method to see the generated SQL. Or use something like LINQPad to test queries.

`ToTraceString` documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't want to have logging running all the time, specially in production

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird, and will have a small performance cost...

But you could probably do something like compare a known sentinel value that's impossible to a clustered index:

```
var queryId = -123456789;

this.Products
    .Where(p => p.ProductId != -queryId);
```

The generated SQL will contain the Id:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = -456789
SELECT ....
FROM [Product] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ProductId] <> @p0
```

I completely **don't** recommend doing something like this in production :D

If the column you're comparing to doesn't have a index, you'll end up with a horrible table scan, that will kill performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MiniProfiler, it can give you a handy little panel that shows what SQL is getting produced in various places within your requests. It includes the names of all the methods on the stack at the point where the query was run. That's not exactly the same as providing a full string representation of the LINQ query, but it may actually be what you're looking for.

[image: MiniProfiler screenshot]